# display latest sensor data from MYSQL to TextView Android Studio

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to display the latest sensor data from MYSQL to TextView in Android. the problem is there is no error display but data did not display either.

PHP gives output

> {"result":[{"temperature":"15","humidity":"14"}]}

this is my MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView temp, hum;
    String id;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        hum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humText);
    }
    //no output, no error (-.-)
    public void getData() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/ethernet/get_data2.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        // this method will interact with UI, display result sent from doInBackground method
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            temp.setText(json_data.getString("temperature"));
            hum.setText(json_data.getString("humidity"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have removed PHP code from the question and tagged it with Android not the IDE. Do not tag with IDE unless your question is about the IDE itself. Please read [ask]

Comment: From where `getData()` is called? Where is the code to update the text view?